# Copying data from one schema to another in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose-schema

Hello new mongoose user here.  I am trying to create a simple web app that takes data from one schema and duplicates it in another schema. I have linked them in their respective schemas:

Trying to push selected groceries into the list schema, but when creating a post route, i am having trouble accessing the info i need.

```
const GrocerySchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   aisle: Number,

  list: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "List",
  },
});

const ListSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  groceries: [
   {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Grocery",
    },
  ],
});
```

Can submit the form and have access one of the ids, but not really sure if there is a way to access the other. Sorry if this is a dumb question or not enough information. Thanks for any help!

```
<ul>
  <% groceries.forEach(function(grocery) { %>
  <li>
    <a href="/groceries/<%= grocery.id %>"
       ><%= grocery.name %> <%=`Aisle: ${grocery.aisle}`%></a>
    <form action="/list/<%= list.id %>/add" method="post">. //(or grocery.id here?
      <button>add to list</button>
     </form>
   </li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```